# Сортировка чисел методом sort

Tags: javascript

```js
var n = [4,6,19,34,32];
console.log(n.sort()); //(5) [19, 32, 34, 4, 6]
```

Comment: потому что по умолчанию, все сортируется как текст

Comment: @ruben в sort Вы не вставили функцию поэтому метод sort сравнивает как текст,  построчно, лексиграфически ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В документации к методу `sort` сказано

> compareFunction
>   Необязательный параметр. Указывает функцию, определяющую порядок сортировки. Если опущен, массив сортируется в соответствии со значениями кодовых точек каждого символа Unicode, полученных путём преобразования каждого элемента в строку.

То есть, ваши числа превращаются в строку и сравниваются, как строки, а для строк `111 < 9`, так как сравнивается посимвольно.

Что бы сортировать числа, нужно делать так:

```
var n = [4,6,19,34,32];
console.log(n.sort((a, b) => a - b)); // [ 4, 6, 19, 32, 34 ]
```

Comment: т.е. сравнивается только 1 число по порядку? 19,(1) 32(3), 34,(3) 4,(4) 6 (6)

Comment: посимвольно, по порядку ( если первые символы одинаковые, сравнивают вторые и так далее )